# How to bind image to GridColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I have a GridColumn with FieldName=="Image". Image is a property type of BitmapImage in MyClass, which is assigned in constructor.

XAML:

```
<dxg:GridColumn  Header="MyImage" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="0" AllowResizing="False" Width="20*"
                HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center"
                FieldName="Image">    
    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
    <dxe:ImageEditSettings MaxWidth="15" />
</dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings></dxg:GridColumn>
```

MyClass:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(ImageType imageType)
    {
        Image = imageType switch
        {
            ImageType.T1=> new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/Assets/Images/information-blue-red.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)),
            ImageType.T2=> new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/Assets/Images/information-blue.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)),
            ImageType.T3=> new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,MyProject;component/Assets/Images/information-red.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)),
            ImageType.T4=> new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/Assets/Images/information-white.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)),
            _ => default
        };
    }

    public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
}
```

So I fill GridControl with ItemsSource of that type. When I execute the program - refreshing method is called at first and everything is OK, I mean that each cell contains needing image. But if I refresh it again(calling such method, which is asynchronous) - ItemsSource is being filled again, and MyClass objects are being created without any problems, but I'm getting an error, that an object is in another thread, so it is inaccessible, after refreshing. I don't know exactly, which object, but I'm sure, that's related to Image property, because I've tested that without such column, and result was OK.

ERROR:

System.InvalidOperationException: "The calling thread cannot access this object because another thread owns this object."

Comment: Consider to edit question to ask about single problem. You can ask another question separately and refer to previous if needed. Also see [mcve].

Comment: @Sinatr I can ask once at 90 min, so I've decided to unite two questions, because they are related to each other

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735/299295). Single question per post is a rule, otherwise your question will get closed as "needs more focus" and you get no answers at all.

Comment: @Sinatr, so can I edit this question to leave one?

Comment: Yes please, but make sure to read [mcve], none of both questions is considered good yet. You have to show *enough* code/xaml and exact error you get (full message with call stack)).

Comment: I suggest to use ListBox and add userControls to this

Comment: For your error use dispatcher.invoke

Comment: @Akbar, do you mean, that I should make GridColumnTemplate, put there ListBox, and then put Image to ListBox?

Comment: @ХарламовДаниил I mean Create your custom usercontrol (with label and image) and bind this and add in your listbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MyClass constructor seems to be called in a thread other than the UI thread. It should hence take care for making the BitmapImage in the Image property cross-thread accessible by freezing it.

The property should also be readonly, or it should fire a change notification when it is set.

And there is no need to set `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute` because a Pack URI is always absolute.

```
public MyClass(ImageType imageType)
{
    var name = imageType switch
    {
        ImageType.T1 => "information-blue-red.png",
        ImageType.T2 => "information-blue.png",
        ImageType.T3 => "information-red.png",
        ImageType.T4 => "information-white.png",
        _ => null
    };

    if (name != null)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(
            "pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/Assets/Images/" + name);

        var image = new BitmapImage(uri);
        image.Freeze(); // here
        Image = image;

        // alternatively, call Image = BitmapFrame.Create(uri);
    }
}

public ImageSource Image { get; }
```